# How to give space above the anchor name <a name="number"></a>

Tags: anchor, spaces, anchor-scroll

I making many anchor name for redirecting on different section in a single page. please check here http://astrologyvaastu.com/numerology2 if you click on any number it will move you on its description in the same page.

I have a sticky navigation bar here. and that is creating the problem because on clicking any number it moves to that section but some part of that description hides behind the navigation bar.

I am using this code

```
<a href="#number1">1</a>
<a name="number1"></a>
```

Can anybody tell me what to do, to stop this description below the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<br />` tag to give some space

or you can give some `margin-top`

Also your website is not accessible to me, please make a fiddle for you problem

Comment: Surely `<br />` isn't the hammer of choice in 2014! (Also, it's no so simple here; that will *extra* leave space, but that's not really the issue with the sticky bar covering the navigated-to-anchor.)